# How can i automatically detect the path of mysqldump.exe?

Tags: vb.net, mysql

I am new in vb.net, how can i do dynamically detect the path "E:\xampp\mysql\bin\"?Here is my codes below and this is work.Please Help me. Thanks a lot in advance :).

```
mp.StartInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe"
mp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = False
mp.StartInfo.WorkingDirectory = "E:\xampp\mysql\bin\"
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = True
mp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = True
mp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = True
mp.Start()
Dim sw As StreamWriter = mp.StandardInput
Dim Sr As StreamReader = mp.StandardOutput

sw.WriteLine("mysqldump -t -u root DB table1 table2 --where=reset=0 > dump.sql ")
sw.Close()
mp.WaitForExit()
mp.Close()
```

Comment: Are you asking if you can detect the location my `mysqldump.exe` at runtime?

Comment: Im asking how to detect mysqldump automatically. ex. I install xampp in any Drive when i run my codes the working directory automatic detected the "path" of mysqldump. :) by the way thank's for your reply man . :D